# Why is ulimit -u higher than /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, proc, ulimit

On my system `ulimit -u` reports `63172` and `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` reports `32768`.

Why is it that the value for `ulimit -u` is higher than the kernel's value? From my understanding, `ulimit -u` shows the max processes a user can have, not system-wide. `pid_max` is supposed to be system-wide via the kernel. It seems wrong to me that `ulimit -u` is higher than `pid_max`, wouldn't this mean that a user could cause PIDs to wrap around if they spawned enough processes? Also, if the `pid_max` value is hit by something a user is doing, won't that cause the `No more processes error` to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIDs *do* wrap around in normal usage.  That's not a problem at all; the kernel ensures that new PIDs don't collide with existing PIDs.  Nothing says that PIDs have to be monotomically increasing; process 12345 could easily `fork()` and have a child process of 5001.

In this scenario, yes, a user could potentially use up all process slots and prevent further `fork()` type activity from occurring.  If this is a problem in your environment then you need to tune the ulimit values in `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.d/*`

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the system will run out of process slots before the user's limit is reached.  The man page of `setrlimit` says:

> #### RLIMIT_NPROC
>
> The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux, threads) that can be created for the real user  ID  of               the calling process.  Upon encountering this limit, `fork(2)` fails with the error `EAGAIN`.  This limit is not enforced               for processes that have either the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability.

The return value of `EAGAIN` strongly implies that this is a limit on concurrent threads, and that once a child has exited, a subsequent `fork()` may succeed.